# Is this "Elegant" algorithm for logarithm by Zeckendorf representation, the same as an 'efficient' algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, fibonacci-numbers

The [algorithm here](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=zeckendorf-logarithm) which computes the exponent $b$ given a base $a$, and given $n$ = $a \wedge b$, appears no better to me than simply counting the number of times we divide $n$ through by the base $a$ until the quotient is less than $a$ and outputting that result, which will be even less work since we compute the largest power of $a$ greater than $n$ in the first step anyway.

Yet the author discusses it at some length, and provides computer code for it. Am I missing something about this that makes it elegant? I admit it is cool, but not particularly efficient or elegant.

Comment: I guess it actually does less work than dividing through by $a$ $b$-times since it computes not powers of $a$ but an 'exponential Fibonacci' in the first step. Maybe this makes it better.

Comment: But it doesn't appear to provide a significant advantage over the binary equivalent, which is also constant storage and logarithmic in $b$.  One benefit of Fibonacci is fewer $1$s in the representation, but it comes at a higher cost of finding the first bit.

Comment: A funny side note is that the decomposition of 95, that the author gives in the comments, is wrong, namely 95 = 65 + 21 + 8 + 1. But 65 is no Fibonacci number; it should be 95=89+5+1.

Comment: The proof of the existence and uniqness of the decomposition is also pretty bloated. If $F(k)$ is the largest Fibonacci number smaller $n$, then $n-F(k)<F(k-1)$ follows immediately, because otherwise $n\geq F(k)+F(k-1)=F(k+1)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @ElmarZander haha. yes! on all points.

Comment: @ErickWong yeh got to acknowledge the cost of that first bit.